# Google Sheet + Apps Script add more link anchor to the dialog box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi if I wanted to add more then just one link to this dialog box how would I do that I've tried multiple ways but no success

```
function Links(){
  showAnchor('Link','http://LINK IN HERE');
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"demo");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getLinks() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Links');
  const sr = 2;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  var html='';
  vs.forEach(r=>{
    html+= `<br><a href="${r[1]}">${r[0]}</a>`
  });
  return html;

}

function showMyAnchors() {
  var html = '<html><body>';
  html += '<div id="links"></div>'
  html += '<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  html += '<script>';
  html += 'window.onload = function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(hl){document.getElementById("links").innerHTML=hl;}).getLinks();}';
  html += '</script>';
  html += '</body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "demo");
}
```

Links Sheet:

| Name | Link |
| --- | --- |
| Link1 | https://google.com |
| Link2 | https://google.com |